# Build unsigned APK file with Android Studio

Tags: android, build, apk, android-studio

I'm developing an Android app with the Android Developer Tool.
Now I tried the new Android Studio, everything works fine if connect my smartphone with the PC and directly run the program in the Android Studio.
But now I want to test the program with other smartphones without connecting them to my PC.

The ADT creates the .apk file under "projectname/bin" every time you compile the program. How I see it at the moment, Android Studio doesn't do that.

So, my question is: Is it possible to create an unsigned .apk file with Android Studio?

Comment: Technically, what you want is an apk signed with a debug key.  An apk that is actually unsigned will be refused by the device.

Comment: FYI we should always prefer exporting signed apps as answered by @Nirmal Dhara. This is much safer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Will it always be refused?

Comment: I solve it with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56201481/8471798

Answer (score 373, accepted):

I would recommend you to build your APK file with Gradle:

- Click the dropdown menu in the toolbar at the top (Open 'Edit Run/Debug configurations' dialog)
- Select "Edit Configurations"
- Click the "+"
- Select "Gradle"
- Choose your module as a Gradle project
- In Tasks: enter `assemble`
- Press Run

Your unsigned APK is now located in

```
ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk
```

For detailed information on how to use Gradle, this tutorial is good to go: [Building with Gradle in Android Studio](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html#building_gradle). I also wrote a [blog post](https://bpoiss.com/build-unsigned-apk-file-with-android-studio/) on how to build an unsigned APK with Gradle.

**If you moved your project from the other IDE and don't want to recompile**, you may find your APK file that was already built in the IDE you moved from:

- If you generated the Project with Android Studio, the APK file will be found in `ProjectName/ProjectName/build/apk/...`
- Imported the project from eclipse: File should be in the same directory. Go to `Project` - `Show in Explorer`. There you should find the bin folder where your APK file is located in.
- Imported from IntelliJ, the location would be `ProjectName/out/production/...`

**Side note:** 
As Chris Stratton mentioned in his comment:

> Technically, what you want is an APK signed with a debug key. An APK 
>   that is actually unsigned will be refused by the device.

Comment: Yes i imported the project from eclipse.

But i my case the bin folder isn't touched by the Android Studio.
With a bit searching i found it by my self.

In my case the .apk was located in "projectname/out/production/projectname/"

Comment: This should be only in case if you switched from IntelliJ

Comment: I am generating the project directly with Studio but there is no folder named "bin" in any of the folders of the project. And in "build" folder there are only two folders namely "res" and "source" and no "bin" folder. can you suggest me something now?

Comment: I am in the same situation as Himanshu, but my "build" folder leads to an "intermediates" folder. But no "bin."

Comment: Fyi, under project structure you may need to go modules - choose app - locate build/apk - and include in build. Mine was excluded by default so when I searched project folders build/apk was missing. If excluded, to include simply highlight folder and click red exclude icon to reinclude again.

Comment: A plain `assemble` builds all variants and flavors. Looking at the contents of META-INF, they're all signed. What if I want to run jarsigner manually?

Comment: `Click the dropdown menu in the toolbar at the top` This is so general. What dropdown menu? What toolbar?

Comment: @dthree you can click "Run" on the top menu bar, and select "Edit Configurations" from the dropdown

Comment: How to implement flavors?

Comment: For me `.apk` file obtained this way failed to install, with `InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -15` in logcat and contentless error essage displayed in UI.

Comment: i got his error 'Could not set process working directory to 'C:\Users\marad\.gradle\daemon\5.2.1\My Application': could not set current directory (errno 2)'

Comment: In Tasks: enter `assemble` means, where I need to do?

Answer (score 235):

According to [Build Unsigned APK with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466227/android-build-unsigned-apk-with-gradle) you can simply build your application with gradle.
In order to do that:

1. click on the drop down menu on the toolbar at the top (usually with android icon and name of your application)
2. select `Edit configurations`
3. click plus sign at top left corner or press `alt+insert`
4. select `Gradle`
5. choose your module as `Gradle project`
6. in `Tasks:` enter `assemble`
7. press `OK`
8. press play

After that you should find your unsigned 'apk' in directory
`ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk`

Comment: + edit build.gradle with android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    } [....] } and it works! thank you

Comment: Thank you marcin ... It worked.. One thing to notice is I could not find "outputs/apk" folder in the Android Studio.. It only appeared in the file system..

Comment: Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'bin'.

Comment: 2nd vote. This should be the Correct Answer. I had this problem on a clean android studio install with project import. You have to go through this manual setup to get any apk files from a build.

Comment: It works in 1.5.1, but actually build whole project apks even if single module has been selected.

Comment: You need to go out of the src folder in Android Studio.

Comment: For me `.apk` file obtained this way failed to install, with `InstallAppProgress: Installation error code: -15` in logcat and contentless error essage displayed in UI.

Answer (score 99):

The easiest way, I guess:

- Open Gradle tab on the right side
- Double click    YourProject/:app/assemble (or assembleDebug)
- You'll find the apk here
  .../YourProject/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, much simpler than accepted answer, and allows not to build apk at each run

Answer (score 54):

just go to BUILD->Build APK and it's done

Comment: +1. A VERY simple method. BTW, you can find the generated APK at `AndroidStudioProjects/<APP NAME>/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`

Comment: as simple as that, thank you very much, it worked, appreciate it.

Answer (score 25):

AndroidStudio 3.4

[image]

After `Grade Build Running` complete, you will see the notification at bottom-right corner like.

[image]

Click on `locate` and you will see your debuggable APK

Answer (score 21):

**Step 1**
Open android studio . Build -> Generate Signed APK… . now click on “Generate Signed APK”.

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

Click Create new.

**Step 3**

Fill the details and click ok.
[image]

jks key details,It will go back to previous window.

[image]

Click Next, and give the password which you stored in key.

**Step 4**

[image]

Now click Finish and wait to complete the building process.

[image]

Now apk generated successfully. Click show in Explorer.

[image]

If you need more details please visit and check the live demo http://javaant.com/how-to-make-apk-file-in-android-studio/#.VwzedZN96Hs

Comment: Question asks for unsigned apk

Comment: not sure if you understood the question. the question is for unsigned apk not signed.

Answer (score 20):

In Android Studio:

1. Build
2. Build APK(s)
3. Wait and go to the location shown in a pop-up window. On right bottom side

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it is possible to create an unsigned .apk with Android Studio!

Highlight the Project in your package explorer or project column, and then `File` - `Project Structure` - `Artifacts` - `+` - `Android Application` - `From module 'your app'` and then you can change the location and some other options. I enable build on make, just for ease.

Comment: it is popping up the message "We will provide a UI to configure project settings later. Until then, please manually edit your build.gradle file(s.)" Now what should i do?

Comment: and what if I don't have any “Artifacts” there?

Comment: Hit the plus sign in the top left and you can get to Android Application

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/artifacts.html  what is the point of using artifacts?   I thought it was to generate an unsigned apk debug apk, etc but it seems as if you can simply go to the build/apk folder to get the unsigned apk so long as you run assemblerelease from gradle menu (at least in intellij IDE).  I just  configured an artifact but I'm having trouble figuring out what to truly do with it.  Can someone please help clarify the difference and use or point me in the right direction?

Comment: @cjayem13 Some projects don't use Gradle.

Answer (score 14):

```
Build -> Build APK     //unsigned app


Build -> Generate Signed APK  //Signed app
```

Answer (score 12):

With Android Studio 2.2.3 on OSX I just used the top menu:

```
Build > Build APK
```

It opened Finder with the `.apk` file. This won't generate a signed APK. You can select `Generate Signed APK` from the same menu if needed.

Comment: I tried to generate a signed APK but it is asking for a key store path. What is suppose to be provided there?

Answer (score 10):

Just go to Your Application\app\build\outputs\apk

and copy both to phone and install app-debug.apk

Comment: is it really necessary to copy both files?

Answer (score 5):

**For unsigned APK:** Simply set signingConfig null. It will give you appName-debug-unsigned.apk

```
debug {
     signingConfig null
}
```

And build from Build menu. Enjoy

**For signed APK:**

```
signingConfigs {
        def keyProps = new Properties()
        keyProps.load(rootProject.file('keystore.properties').newDataInputStream())
        internal {
            storeFile file(keyProps.getProperty('CERTIFICATE_PATH'))
            storePassword keyProps.getProperty('STORE_PASSWORD')
            keyAlias keyProps.getProperty('KEY_ALIAS')
            keyPassword keyProps.getProperty('KEY_PASSWORD')
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.internal
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.internal
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

keystore.properties file

```
CERTIFICATE_PATH=./../keystore.jks
STORE_PASSWORD=password
KEY_PASSWORD=password
KEY_ALIAS=key0
```

Answer (score 4):

Following work for me:

Keep following setting blank if you have made in build.gradle.

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storePassword ""
            keyAlias ""
            keyPassword ""
        }
    }
```

and choose Gradle Task from your Editor window. It will show list of all flavor if you have created.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

--- Create new config in signingConfigs

```
unsigned {
        //do not sign
    }
```

--- Create build type in buildTypes

```
unsigned {
        versionNameSuffix '-unsigned'
    }
```

--- Go to build variants and chose unsigned standard. Build project.

--- Go to "outputs/apk" and find "XXX-unsigned.apk". To check if it is unsigned try to install it to device - you'll fail.

Comment: This does not work. You need to define the signinigConfig a bit different (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/18121401/624109)
`signingConfigs{
    unsigned{
        storePassword = ""
        keyAlias = ""
        keyPassword = ""
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

Now in Android Studio v1.1.0 should be:

1. select `Run` > `Run <your app>`
2. find .apk file in `<your app>\build\outputs\apk`

Comment: I am using 1.2.1.1 but your approach does not work. I have to create a Gradle Assembly!

Answer (score 1):

Android studio also create the apk file on every time compile the program, just go to your workspace folder and find app->build->outputs-> then you can see the apk file.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the dropdown near the run button on toolbar,

1. Select "Edit Configurations"
2. Click the "+"
3. Select "Gradle"
4. Choose your module as Gradle project
5. In Tasks: enter assemble

Now press ok,

all you need to do is now select your configuration from the dropdown and press run button. It will take some time. Your unsigned apk is now located in

```
Project\app\build\outputs\apk
```