# Build Unsigned APK with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Currently I'm trying to learn Gradle to build Android APKs. How to set an option in gradle to build an unsigned APK?

Comment: By unsigned you mean even with the debug key ? Why ?

Comment: nope. release version but unsigned

Comment: @tbruyelle Amazon Appstore requires unsigned apks.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You don't have to set any option, just run the usual task:

```
$ gradle assemble
```

This will generate two files in project/build/apk/

```
app-debug-unaligned.apk 
app-release-unsigned.apk
```

Comment: @rafaello: Iknow it's a while ago. But my solution (answer above) doesn't work anymore (Why?... I don't know). Now I tried you solution and it worked for me. Thanks a lot! The mistake I made in earlier time was to set a signConfig in the flavor that I wanted unsigned... Now I removed the signConfig and everything works fine! It's just annoying to this over the command line...

Comment: Do you need to have signing config stuff for this to work? even if it's just the debug one?

Comment: Go to `Run > Edit configurations` and add a new gradle job with tasks "assemble". Now run your new job. The `myapp-debug.apk` is under `<module>/build/outputs/apk`

Comment: @rafaello  I get an error: >Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky try the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087330/gradle-eclipse-plugin-could-not-find-method-jcenter-for-arguments-on-repo see if it solves your problem

Comment: Here are some detailed instructions to do what vault is describing in the comment above https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing

Answer (score 20):

To generate an unsigned apk do the following:

- define a `signingConfig` with empty configuations like this:

  ```
  signingConfigs{
      unsigned{
          storePassword = ""
          keyAlias = ""
          keyPassword = ""
      }
  }
  ```
- define in the `buildTypes` for your release Version with the unsigned Configuration:

  ```
  buildTypes{
      release{
          signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
      }
  }
  ```

I get this from the [adt-dev group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/adt-dev/unsigned%2420apk/adt-dev/soWPptphBfw/_SuycdcJHwoJ), where Xavier Ducrohet write:

> The current behavior is to check that the signing config is fully
>   configured(*) and if it is, it generates a signed APK, otherwise an
>   unsigned APK.
>
> (*) fully configured right now means the value for
>   store, alias and passwords are present, but does not include that the
>   keystore is present.

**UPDATE 2013-12-19**

As withoutclass mentioned this doesn't work with the gradle plugin version 0.6.3.

Anyway it's possible to generate an unsigned APK with gradle: just let the signingConfig entry of a flavor or buildType empty. It should look like this:

```
productFlavors{
    // with this config you should get a "MyProject-flavorUnsigned-release-unsigned.apk"
    flavorUnsigned{
        versionCode = 9
        packageName defaultPkgName
    }
}

buildTypes{
    // with this config you should get a "MyProject-release-unsigned.apk"
    release{
        packageNameSuffix '.release'
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me anymore. But rafaellos answer is quite good. Added a post to ADT Dev Group on G+:https://plus.google.com/117954254390243608387/posts/N5dTMNS5UGv

Comment: This doesn't work as the build will fail stating that there are no value specified for the required fields. plugin version 0.6.3

Comment: @withoutclass: Your right. I updated my answer and explained how can generate an unsigned apk with the newest gradle version.

Comment: this doesn't work if your release build has a signing config. It will sign the app using the release config. Plugin version 0.7.0.

Comment: Ok, I still use the plugin version 0.6.+, because there is no update for AS 0.4.0 in the "dev channel". Now is the question: how can i generate an unsigned apk with plugin version 0.7.0? Do I need an additionally buildType "unsigned" where I don't declare a `signingConfig`? This wouldn't be a nice solution because the count of buildVariants increase...

Answer (score 11):

just assign null to signingConfig

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      signingConfig null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make a build type act that is unsigned (just like a debug build), do the following:

```
myBuildType {
    initWith debug
    ...
}
```

Comment: Debug build is signed by autogenerated keystore