# Does anyone know how to build a gradle parent project with subprojects that uses the tomcat plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am devolping a parent java project with 3 subprojects.  I am using gradle as its build tool.  I am new to using gradle for my build tool.

I am trying to get it to when I run the parent project, the parent project and possibly two of the subprojects automatically run on a web application (Tomcat web container).

I found a helpful website  https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin/blob/master/README.md

I see that I have to add a few things to the parent projects build.gradle.  For instance:

```
apply plugin: 'tomcat'
```

which defines the following tasks:

tomcatRun: Starts a Tomcat instance and deploys the exploded web application to it.
tomcatRunWar: Starts a Tomcat instance and deploys the WAR to it.
tomcatStop: Stops the Tomcat instance.
tomcatJasper: Runs the JSP compiler (Jasper) and turns JSP pages into Java source using.

I would need to run the "tomcatRun" and the "tomcatStop" task.  Where should I declare each task?  I think I should declare it under repositories { } tomcatRun { ...., but I am not sure.  Is that where I would declare it?  Do I have to declare the httpPort if my port is 8080?  I ask, because 8080 is the default value and I am using the default value?

I have to declare the classpath for tomcat (classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.7') inside the dependencies.  Right?

For each of the subprojects that I want to add to tomcat, do I have to delare the classpath in their dependencies in their 'project' section (project (':subproject-a') { dependences { classpath ... ?

I added aplly plugin:'tomcat', but when I run it I get "Plugin with id 'tomcat' not found.  What am I missing?

Where do I define the tomcat options?

```
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar]*.contextPath = 'stock-webservice'
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar, tomcatStop]*.stopPort = 8081
[tomcatRun, tomcatRunWar, tomcatStop]*.stopKey = 'stopKey'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of your questions should have been answered by the plugin's documentation. First of all, the tasks you mention are provided by the plugin. You do not need to declare them yourself. Run `gradle tasks` for a list of task available to your project. If a default is given for a property, then you don't need to provide it. Tomcat dependencies are assigned to the `tomcat` configuration. You can just copy/paste the relevant code from the README file. If the plugin cannot be found, that means you didn't declare the plugin dependency for your buildscript's classpath. Again you can copy/paste the relevant code from the documentation.

In general I'd recommend reading up on the Gradle online documentation first to get a better understanding of the tool.

Comment: I was able to get it to run successfully with a lot of changes.
1.  I made changes to the classpath.  
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.gradle.api.plugins/gradle-tomcat-plugin/1.0"/>
2.  I added the buildscript specifics (from your readme) to the build.gradle.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:1.0'
    }
}
which was not working originally, "Could ...", lead me to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087330/gradle-eclipse-plugin-could-not-find-method-jcenter-for-arguments-on-repo)

Comment: 3.  manually add the gradle-tomcat-plugin-1.0 to gradle's plugin directory
4.  upgraded gradle 
add     tomcat "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-coyote:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
to the subproject I want to run on tomcat.

Comment: I have: [tomcatRun, tomcatStop]*.stopKey = 'stopKey' how do I stop Tomcat from running?