# Gradle Cargo Plugin in Eclipse failing

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to use Gradle Cargo plugin in my project.

**Here is my build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'cargo'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-cargo-plugin:1.4'
    }
}

ext.springVersion = '4.0.2.RELEASE';
ext.jerseyVersion = '2.6';
ext.jettyVersion = '9.1.3.v20140225';
httpPort = 8099;

def springDependencies = ["org.springframework:spring-core:$springVersion",
    "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion",
    "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion",
    "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion",
    "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion"]

def jettyDependencies = ["org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:$jettyVersion",
    "org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:$jettyVersion"]

def jerseyDependencies = ["org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:$jerseyVersion",
    'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0']

ext.libs = [
        springDependencies : springDependencies,
        jerseyDependencies : jerseyDependencies,
        guava: 'com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1',
        junit: 'junit:junit:4.11'
    ]

dependencies {
    compile springDependencies;
    compile jerseyDependencies;
    compile("org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-spring3:$jerseyVersion"){
        exclude group: 'org.springframework'
    };
    compile libs.guava;
    testCompile libs.junit;
}
```

On refreshing the dependencies, I am getting the following error: `org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on repository container`.

**Here is the complete stack trace:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\Workspaces\TestProjects\springjerseygradle\build.gradle' line: 17

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'springjerseygradle'.
> Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on repository container.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'springjerseygradle'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:116)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildScriptProcessor.evaluate(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:464)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:77)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$ConfigureProject.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer$ConfigureProject.execute(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.configure(AbstractProject.java:440)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.allprojects(AbstractProject.java:435)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:73)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DelegatingBuildModelAction.run(DelegatingBuildModelAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:103)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not find method jcenter() for arguments [] on repository container.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:172)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at build_5ru6nl8ep0dulqvskgg5mshf5d$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(E:\Workspaces\TestProjects\springjerseygradle\build.gradle:17)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:133)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.configure(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.configure(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:133)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.AbstractScriptHandler.repositories(AbstractScriptHandler.java:66)
    at build_5ru6nl8ep0dulqvskgg5mshf5d$_run_closure1.doCall(E:\Workspaces\TestProjects\springjerseygradle\build.gradle:15)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:58)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:133)
    at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.buildscript(AbstractProject.java:893)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$buildscript.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$buildscript.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.buildscript(ProjectScript.groovy:42)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$buildscript.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_5ru6nl8ep0dulqvskgg5mshf5d.run(E:\Workspaces\TestProjects\springjerseygradle\build.gradle:14)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 53 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.53 secs
```

Here are the environment details:
Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 2,
Installed Gradle version: 1.11,
SpringSource Update Site for Gradle Integration for Eclipse:  [Link](http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle)

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087330/gradle-eclipse-plugin-could-not-find-method-jcenter-for-arguments-on-repo), it is mentioned that the problem is with old version of gradle. But I am already using latest version of Gradle. What am I missing here?

Comment: Probably your Gradle Eclipse plugin is set up to use an older Gradle version.

Comment: Instead of refreshing the dependencies from IDE, I tried doing 'gradle clean build'. Even then it is failing.

Comment: I tried pointing Gradle to my installation folder rather than defaulting to 'Use Gradle wrapper's default'. On refreshing dependencies, I don't see any error coming now. But on doing gradle clean build, it is again throwing errors. It is throwing a message that it could not resolve dependencies that are getting resolved if I just remove cargo related information from build.gradle

Comment: Sounds like an unrelated problem.

Comment: You will need to use Gradle 1.7 or higher. The method `jcenter()` was added in [version 1.7](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.7/release-notes#jcenter-repository-support) and didn't exist before. Make sure you actually execute the build with that version.