# How to generate signed and unsigned APK's using gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, android-gradle-plugin

I need to generate both unsigned and signed release apks using gradle command line (`gradlew assembleRelease` is the command im using now)

The apks must be aligned. I checked this: [Build Unsigned APK with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466227/android-build-unsigned-apk-with-gradle) but it seems to be an old way to achieve this, now it does not work and something has changed in lastest versions of android and gradle compilation. And also i need to generate both apks at same time, not only release mode or unsigned mode

Comment: Apologies for my initial answer, I misread the question

Comment: run `gradle clean assemble` (this will execute `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelease`. Make sure the debug buildType has no singingConfig, but the release buildType has got one.

Comment: So, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 9):

I know it's pretty old answer but it still might help someone gain your goal without adding extra flavour (even as in my case it might be challenging because many dependencies in the project).

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    release { ... }
  }

  productFlavors {
    signed { 
      signingConfig (checkUnsigned() ? null : signingConfigs.release)

    }
}

def checkUnsigned ()  {
    return project.hasProperty("unsigned")
}
```

In order to use it just use

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

or

```
gradle assembleRelease '-Punsigned'
```

for creating unsigned (quotes for CI, otherwise it might not be needed)

Disadvantage of the solution is just when you want to assemble several flavours in one line
ie

```
gradle assembleRelease assembleDebug assembleRelease '-Punsigned'
```

assembleRelease checks all properties in command line, so first assembleRelease will be callse also with param '-Punsigned'
I resolved this CI issue by using 2 commands - one for signed, other for unsigned versions

```
gradle assembleRelease assembleOtherFlavour '-Punsigned'
gradle assembleDebug assembleRelease assembleOtherFlavour
```

Comment: Never is late to help other like me :D Thanks!

Comment: This is lighter weight than adding a new build variant. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I think `buildTypes` is a more suitable place than `productFlavors`.
You can extend your release build with replacing signingConfig.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ....
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    releaseUnsigned.initWith(buildTypes.release)
    releaseUnsigned {
        signingConfig null
    }
}
```

Then for building both APK-files:

```
./gradlew assemble
```

Or if you want only release builds

```
./gradlew assembleRelease assembleReleaseUnsigned
or ./gradlew assR assRU
```

If you really want to use only assembleRelease task, you can make this dependency

```
assembleRelease.dependsOn assembleReleaseUnsigned
```

And build with just

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: where do you add the line `assembleRelease.dependsOn assembleReleaseUnsigned` ?

Comment: @KhaledOsman anywhere in app/build.gradle, after dependencies {} or other custom tasks.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you linked to is correct - if your chosen variant (i.e. build type + flavor combination) is not using a "signing ready" signing config, gradle will create an unsigned APK.

So you can define a setup like this:

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    release { ... }
  }

  productFlavors {
    signed { 
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release // defined above
    }

    unsigned {} // use the default options
  }
}
```

Then running `./gradlew :app:assembleRelease` will create your APKs:

```
app/build/outputs/apk
├── app-signed-release.apk
├── app-signed-release-unaligned.apk
└── app-unsigned-release-unsigned.apk
```

Comment: I think signingConfig should take place in buildTypes, and flavors are for app logic

Answer (score 2):

It didn't work for me with defining new buildType. But it works with debug/release:

```
 buildTypes {
         release {
                signingConfig null
            }
         debug {
                signingConfig null
            }
    }
```

this will create unsigned apks