# Android studio not generating unsinged apk

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

From my terminal if i run `"gradle assemble"` its only generating following apks. Any one please tell me how do i get default unsigned apk from android studio. I tried creating separate buildType for unsigned with empty keyStore but no use .

```
 - MyApp-debug-unaligned.apk
 - MyApp-debug.apk
 - MyApp-release-unaligned.apk
 - MyApp- release.apk
```

Comment: `MyApp-debug.apk` is the one which you might looking for.

Comment: What would an unsigned apk be used for?

Answer (score 0):

To generate an unsigned apk do the following:

define a signingConfig with empty configuations like this:

```
signingConfigs{
unsigned{
    storePassword = ""
    keyAlias = ""
    keyPassword = ""
}
}
```

define in the buildTypes for your release Version with the unsigned Configuration:

```
buildTypes{
release{
    signingConfig signingConfigs.unsigned
}
}
```

I get this from the adt-dev group, where Xavier Ducrohet write:

The current behavior is to check that the signing config is fully configured(*) and if it is, it generates a signed APK, otherwise an unsigned APK.

(*) fully configured right now means the value for store, alias and passwords are present, but does not include that the keystore is present.
UPDATE 2013-12-19

As withoutclass mentioned this doesn't work with the gradle plugin version 0.6.3.

Anyway it's possible to generate an unsigned APK with gradle: just let the signingConfig entry of a flavor or buildType empty. It should look like this:

```
productFlavors{
// with this config you should get a "MyProject-flavorUnsigned-release-     unsigned.apk"
flavorUnsigned{
    versionCode = 9
    packageName defaultPkgName
}
}

buildTypes{
// with this config you should get a "MyProject-release-unsigned.apk"
release{
    packageNameSuffix '.release'
}
}
```

Answer here: [Build Unsigned APK with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466227/android-build-unsigned-apk-with-gradle)