# Generated apk without Android Studio

Tags: android, teamcity

I need generate an apk when the all tests passed successfully in teamcity, but I need to do it without Android Studio because the teamcity is installed in another machine.
Any help is welcome, thanks

I set up a build step with Gradle where:
**Gradle task:** assembleDebug
**Working directory:** path to my project
**Gradle home path:** C:/gradle-2.8 
**JDK:** default (i have set up JAVA_HOME environment variable )
 Now, when I run the build fails, in the build logs shows

```
[Step 1/5] Starting: C:\gradle-2.8\bin\gradle.bat --init-script C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\gradle-runner\scripts\init.gradle -d -s gradle assembleDebug
[14:56:35][Step 1/5] in directory: C:\BuildAgent1\work\45bc198e86ccc58\IntegracionContinua\Android\BuilderToDo
[14:56:36][Step 1/5] 14:56:36.222 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Native-platform posix files is not available.  Continuing with fallback.
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.089 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Starting Build
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.092 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.092 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Current dir: C:\BuildAgent1\work\45bc198e86ccc58\IntegracionContinua\Android\BuilderToDo
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.093 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.093 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Build file: null
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.150 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Software Loopback Interface 1
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.151 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? true
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.153 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.153 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.154 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.154 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Software Loopback Interface 1
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.155 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Adaptador de red de depuración de kernel de Microsoft
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.156 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.157 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.157 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding loopback multicast interface Adaptador de red de depuración de kernel de Microsoft
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.158 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Adding IP addresses for network interface Controladora Gigabit Ethernet PCI-E Marvell Yukon 88E8056
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.159 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a loopback interface? false
[14:56:37][Step 1/5] 14:56:37.160 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.inet.InetAddressFactory] Is this a multicast interface? true 
[Step 1/5] 14:56:38.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Starting to build the build sources.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.019 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.buildsrc.BuildSourceBuilder] Gradle source dir does not exist. We leave.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.021 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.021 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.103 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor] Timing: Processing settings took: 0.082 secs
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.106 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings evaluated using settings file 'C:\master\settings.gradle'.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.260 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' from state Known to Created
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.268 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks' rule action Project.<init>.tasks()
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.268 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks using Project.<init>.tasks()
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.270 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.270 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks' rule action Project.<init>.tasks()
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.271 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks using Project.<init>.tasks()
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.282 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state Created.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.301 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'nodeInitializerRegistry' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.301 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'nodeInitializerRegistry' rule action Project.<init>.nodeInitializerRegistry()
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.301 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating nodeInitializerRegistry using Project.<init>.nodeInitializerRegistry()
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.302 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'nodeInitializerRegistry' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.305 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] Looking for project properties from: C:\BuildAgent1\work\45bc198e86ccc58\IntegracionContinua\Android\BuilderToDo\gradle.properties
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.305 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader] project property file does not exists. We continue!
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.307 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Projects loaded. Root project using build file 'C:\BuildAgent1\work\45bc198e86ccc58\IntegracionContinua\Android\BuilderToDo\build.gradle'.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.307 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Included projects: [root project 'BuilderToDo']
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.405 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.api.Script] Starting Gradle in TeamCity build 241
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.473 [INFO] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Evaluating root project 'BuilderToDo' using build file 'C:\BuildAgent1\work\45bc198e86ccc58\IntegracionContinua\Android\BuilderToDo\build.gradle'.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.475 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 0.002 secs
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.511 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] All projects evaluated.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.517 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Script] Received following incremental setting: false
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.518 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Script] Incremental building is not enabled
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.545 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' from state Created to SelfClosed
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.546 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state RulesDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.546 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state DefaultsApplied.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.546 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state Initialized.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.546 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state Mutated.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.547 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state Finalized.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.547 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' to state SelfClosed.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.548 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks' from state SelfClosed to SelfClosed
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.548 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.components' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.548 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.components' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(components)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.548 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.components using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(components)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.549 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.components' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.550 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.dependencies' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.550 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.dependencies' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(dependencies)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.dependencies using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(dependencies)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.dependencies' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.551 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.dependencyInsight' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.552 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.dependencyInsight' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(dependencyInsight)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.552 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.dependencyInsight using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(dependencyInsight)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.552 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.dependencyInsight' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.553 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.help' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.553 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.help' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(help)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.553 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.help using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(help)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.554 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.help' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.554 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.init' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.init' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(init)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.init using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(init)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.555 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.init' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.model' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.model' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(model)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.556 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.model using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(model)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.557 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.model' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.557 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.projects' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.558 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.projects' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(projects)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.558 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.projects using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(projects)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.558 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.projects' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.properties' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.properties' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(properties)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.559 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.properties using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(properties)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.properties' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.560 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.tasks' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.561 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.tasks' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(tasks)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.561 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.tasks using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(tasks)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.561 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.tasks' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.562 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.wrapper' from state Known to ProjectionsDefined
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.562 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Running model element 'tasks.wrapper' rule action tasks.addPlaceholderAction(wrapper)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.562 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Mutating tasks.wrapper using tasks.addPlaceholderAction(wrapper)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.563 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry] Transitioning model element 'tasks.wrapper' to state ProjectionsDefined.
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.587 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.588 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.588 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.588 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 2.665 secs
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.591 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on cp_init class cache for initialization script 'C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\gradle-runner\scripts\init.gradle' (C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\2.8\scripts\init_7vg4lpvl6y710x06lbh9uy6xb\cp_init).
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.591 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on init class cache for initialization script 'C:\BuildAgent1\plugins\gradle-runner\scripts\init.gradle' (C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\2.8\scripts\init_7vg4lpvl6y710x06lbh9uy6xb\init).
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.593 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 0, cache instances: 0, modules served from cache: 0, artifacts: 0
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.594 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolved configuration cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.594 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.595 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.001 secs
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.595 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\modules-2).
[14:56:38][Step 1/5] 14:56:38.597 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\2.8\plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
```

and I have marked the checkbox Stracktrace and it shows me

```
[Step 1/5] Gradle failure report
[14:56:38]14:56:38.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[14:56:38]14:56:38.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[14:56:38]14:56:38.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[14:56:38]14:56:38.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
[14:56:38]14:56:38.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'BuilderToDo'.
[14:56:38]14:56:38.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[14:56:38]14:56:38.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
[14:56:38]14:56:38.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. 
[14:56:38]14:56:38.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
[14:56:38]14:56:38.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
[14:56:38]14:56:38.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'gradle' not found in root project 'BuilderToDo'.
[14:56:38]14:56:38.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:100)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:75)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.577 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.577 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.577 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.577 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:143)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.579 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.579 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.579 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.579 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.580 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.580 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.580 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.581 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.581 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.581 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.581 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.581 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.582 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.582 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.582 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.582 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.583 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.584 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.585 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.585 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.585 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.585 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.586 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.586 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.586 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
[14:56:38]14:56:38.586 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]  at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
```

I don't know what I doing wrong, anybody can help me

Comment: Did you notice those `build.gradle` files?

Comment: you can use gradle command line. You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Build Unsigned APK with Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466227/android-build-unsigned-apk-with-gradle)

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood, you mean the build step with Gradle?

Comment: If you run `./gradlew tasks` from the command-line, you will see all of the available tasks for your project. These will tell you which one is needed for building your release APK.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I try to do what you tell me and not work yet, it shows me an error about something like :classpath

Comment: I really need a step by step, if it's possible

Comment: "an error about something like..." isn't helpful. We need the complete, exact error message in order to help.

Comment: Also include the exact command which causes the error.