# Generated apk without Android Studio-2

Tags: android, teamcity

@Code-Apprentice this link is the original question [Generated apk without Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35230431/generated-apk-without-android-studio?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I try with `gradlew task` and this is the error

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:275)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:371)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

then I try with `gradle task` and the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'BuilderToDo'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         :BuilderToDo:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
               > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 49.262 secs
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: internet connection issue check please

Comment: my connexion is through a proxy, thas is the problem?

Comment: Maybe m not sure never tried through proxy

Comment: I try to use --offline command line but I get this error: No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 available for offline mode, any idea what I can do?