# Android Studio apk not generating in build folder

Tags: android, android-studio

May be lot of possible duplicates for this question,but my situation is different. Just i downloaded Android Studio in my mac and created one sample application. It is running fine in emulator as well as device. But when i am trying to get apk in build folder it is not showing apk file. Please find the attached screen shot for reference.

My Studio version is: 0.8.6.

[image]

please help me how can i get unsigned apk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build unsigned APK file with Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709848/build-unsigned-apk-file-with-android-studio)

Comment: You have generate apk from GOTO : Build menu > Genrate Signed Apk.

Comment: [Workspace]\[Project]\app\build\outputs\apk

Answer (score 4):

haha , how silly it is there in build path only, but it won't visible in IDE, we have to go Folder structure then it will show apk file like below.

[image]

Comment: Me too having this issue. THe app runs fine in emulator. but no apk at anywhere

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Goto Build Menu >> Click Generate Signed APK..

After Click Generate Signed APK.. it will open Generate Signed APK Wizard now follow this steps :

```
1.Select your Module/Project from DropDown
2.Select KeyStore from path if KeyStore not created then create and give alias,password.
3.Select Destination path where you wan to place your APk and if you have custom pro guard settings then select pro guard using check Run ProGuard option.
```

Comment: i don't want signed apk , i want unsigned apk which was generated defauklt by system

Comment: @Leena,is there any mean to use unsigned apk ?

Comment: There is no reason, but system should generate one unsigned apk like in eclipse -> bin->apk

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio `Feb 2022 build`, you need to execute `Build APK(s)`

[image]