# APK file not showing in android studio. It is possible to generate apk file on some pre define path?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I had confusion about apk file path in Android Studio.

Currently i am using studio version 1.1.0 and in App -> Build ->, There is no folder "outputs".

I had check manually in directory where my project is located. Outputs folder was there and with apk file. But it is not shown in studio.

It is possible that i had make some pre define path and studio automatically generate apk there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709848/build-unsigned-apk-file-with-android-studio

Comment: If you're not on windows open a terminal window and try "find . -name *.apk" in your "Home" folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16620423/3513479 pls chek its help you

Comment: Nope...i google it before writing question....i am using newer version..in my version of studio...apk is generated in app->build->outputs folder...but output folder is not there in studio...thanks for reply..

Comment: @VishalPatel...apk file is generated but not shown output folder in studio....i had checked that link earlier..thank4Reply

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4, it could be generated in

> Build>Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)>Build APK(s)

and found in

> Project>app>build>outputs>apk>debug