# Fails to generate apk file

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Ok, so recently I've been trying to run my application on Android Studio (1.1.0), but every time I try to run it, the following error pops up:

```
Waiting for device
Target device: samsung-blah-blahblah
Uploading file local path: C:\Users\jimmykim9001\AndroidStudioProjects\blahblah\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk 
remote path: /data/local/tmp/blah.com.blah
Local path doesn't exist.
```

Now by doing some research I've come to this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i4WcMIyc8OQ This would have been helpful if I was able to find my apk files when searching my project; however, they're not there, which is strange because I'm pretty sure they're supposed to be created automatically. So I tried to rebuild the project, but that fails half-way through (Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: ). What I need to do is get Android Studio to generate the app-debug.apk file, but I have no idea how. All the links I've found involve moving the file into the right place, but the file itself doesn't exist for me. Any ideas?

Note: I imported a jar file recently and ever since I did that, the problems started. Not sure if this matters or not.

Answer (score 1):

I got your question. I have also faced the same problem some time ago. Let me clue you in , here is some approach i would like to try :-

- Your apk must be here ( if it have been automatically generated)

  > your_app_name\app\build\outputs\apk
- If `app-debug.apk` is not there then , Clear the cache `File -> Invalidate Cache`, then restart your IDE . Then rebuild it.
- Try removing the `jar` you have recently added and rebuild the project.
- you can try re-importing your project.

From above all what worked for me 1st point . Try these .................................best of luck.

Here are some links you might like to see....

[Build unsigned APK file with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709848/build-unsigned-apk-file-with-android-studio)

[Apk location in New Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620366/apk-location-in-new-android-studio/16620423#16620423)