# Unsigned apk generation with Android Studio doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova

I generated my project with Cordova, I'm using Android Studio to develop my app, I can test the app on a connected Android platform, but I'm not able to generate apk. I run Build -> Build APK the IDE says Build APK: APK(s) generated successfully. Reveal in Finder, but I cannot find anywhere the generated APK (I searched it in my filesystem).
I added a build-extras.gradle containing:

```
android { lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
    }
}
```

And in select build variant I choosed debug.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: where you store the apk to ? which location? by default android studio will place it under ur project/app/

Comment: Is there a place to configure this path? I'm using Cordova so a lot of things are already configured

Comment: I solved with this suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709848/build-unsigned-apk-file-with-android-studio?rq=1