# Where is the option "build" (apk) in Android Studio v 3.5.2

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android, and in the tutorials that I have seen it is always compiled by clicking on this option

[image]

But in this new version of Android Studio I am unable to find this option:

[image]

I don't know if it's any use, but if I click run this screen appears, but it asks me to choose a module, and there's nothing in that dropdown

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709848/build-unsigned-apk-file-with-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

Hi there i was also facing the same issue but now i am able to build (apk) on android v3.5.2

I just go through this path:Tools~SDK Manager~ SDK tools download

It works for me hope so it will works for you as well.

Comment: thanks for answeer,I installed that.. now, what is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to build your APK file with Gradle:

- Click the dropdown menu in the toolbar at the top (Open 'Edit Run/Debug configurations' dialog)
- Select "Edit Configurations"
- Click the "+"
- Select "Gradle"
- Choose your module as a Gradle project
- In Tasks: enter `assemble`
- Press Run

Your unsigned APK is now located in

```
ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk
```

For detailed information on how to use Gradle, this tutorial is good to go: [Building with Gradle in Android Studio](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html#building_gradle).

Comment: can you give me screenshot of : `Click the dropdown menu in the toolbar at the top (Open 'Edit Run/Debug configurations' dialog)`   and `Choose your module as a Gradle project` please?

Answer (score 0):

Your project has not been setup as an `Android Project` - these are the options for non-Android projects.

To fix this, you should be able to close the project and re-import it. If you pay attention to the import options, you should be able to sort it out.

Also, if you attempt to import from the wrong directory level for an Android project, you can end up in this situation (where you think you have an Android project).

Answer (score 0):

I found this online check if this helps
https://developer.android.com/studio/run
or refer this 
[Build unsigned APK file with Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709848/build-unsigned-apk-file-with-android-studio)